# Multiple popup handling using java selenium on a travel website

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, popup

I have successfully registered on airbnb website using a username and email now since I have already registered on airbnb the website is asking for password and I am unable to interact with this pop up earlier successfully handled the first pop up with google sign up as I used gmail to create a user .Now I will have to login using password please have a look

```
    package Practice;
    import org.junit.Assert;
    import org.openqa.selenium.*;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.time.Duration;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.Set;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
    
    
    public class Airbnbmumbai
    {
        public static void main(String[]args) throws InterruptedException {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path to chromedriver");
            ChromeOptions ops = new ChromeOptions();
            ops.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
            ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(ops);
            driver.get("https://www.airbnb.co.in/");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.navigate().forward();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            // Clicking on trending //
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class=\"f19g2zq0 dir dir-ltr\"]")).click();
            driver.navigate().forward();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            // Getting the title of the page on starting of the page //
            System.out.println("Page title is : " + driver.getTitle());
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name=\"query\"]")).sendKeys("Mumbai");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class=\"_r1t6ga\"]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class=\"_1gazwvry notranslate\"])[4]")).click();
            driver.navigate().forward();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/header/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[4]/div/div/section/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[4]/div")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class=\"p1kudodg dir dir-ltr\"]")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[@class=\"i98ho2o dir dir-ltr\"])[2]")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/header/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/div/section/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/button[2]/span")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class=\"t1l18xbv dir dir-ltr\"]")).click();
            driver.navigate().forward();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/main/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]")).click();
            System.out.println("Page title is : " + driver.getTitle());
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/main/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[7]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]")).click();
            // Now will work on the second window //
            ArrayList<String> tabs2 = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
            driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(1));
                // Clicking on see all photos //
            System.out.println("Page title is : " + driver.getTitle());
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            driver.navigate().forward();
            JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,450)", "");
            // Clicking on reserve //
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[@class=\"t12u7nq4 dir dir-ltr\"])[2]")).click();
         Thread.sleep(4000);
         driver.navigate().forward();
            js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,450)", "");
            // Signup with google //
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class=\"_1u21f56\"])[2]")).click();
            String parentWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle(); // Store your parent window
            String subWindowHandler = null;
            Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all window handles
            Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()){
                subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
            }
            driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler); // switch to popup window
    
            // Now you are in the popup window, perform necessary actions here
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.navigate().forward();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"identifierId\"]")).sendKeys("username");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.navigate().forward();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"identifierNext\"]/div/button/span")).click();
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            driver.navigate().forward();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"password\"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("Password");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.navigate().forward();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"passwordNext\"]/div/button/span")).click();
            // Since the user is already registered so entering password here //
            System.out.println("Page title is : " + driver.getTitle());
            // Handling the pop up again //
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(4,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.navigate().forward();
            
            driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("Mypassword");
    
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you getting "Couldn’t sign you in,This browser or app may not be secure message?

Comment: No it is asking for password and I am unable to interact with password popup